# Add a new library in android

Tags: android

I need to make a floating circular menu 
And I need to add a library to my project
Finally i found a library that would help me do that

```
implementation 'com.github.recruit-lifestyle:FloatingView:2.4.4'
```

When i add this library in my gradle i get an error

This is the error :

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.recruit-lifestyle:FloatingView:2.4.4.

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.recruit-lifestyle:FloatingView:2.4.4.

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.recruit-lifestyle:FloatingView:2.4.4.
```

does anyone know why is that?!

And I have tried to add other libraries, but every time I get the same error

How can i solve this problem?

**Edit1**
This is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
defaultConfig {
applicatiomId "com.example.project"
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 28
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
testInstrumentationRunner
"androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
release {
minifyEnabled false
proguardFiles getDefultProguardFile ('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
}
}
dependency  {
implementation fileTree (dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayouy:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit::1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
//This is the library I want to add
implementation 'com.github.recruit-lifestyle:FloatingView:2.4.4'
}
```

**Edit2**
My build.gradle (Project)

```
buildscript {
repositories {
google ()
jcenter ()
}
dependency  {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
}
}
allprojects {
repositoriss {
google ()
jcenter ()
maven {
url "https://jitpack.io"
}
}
}
task clean (type: Delete){
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: This library is a little old and it may be because of the dependencies it uses. Try opening an issue for the developer.

Comment: have you added repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}
to your bulild.gradle file?

Comment: File>project structure>dependencies>add library dependency  and in the form I searched for this library and found it then i clicked applay

Comment: @Ravi Kumar  yes,i did

Comment: Why is Implementation in caps there? Is that a typo?

Comment: SONU SOURAV  sorry yes,it is

Comment: @Android_id , i did

Comment: Could you share build.gradle (project) also?

Comment: @SONU SOURAV i will

Answer (score 1):

Try adding below one:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.recruit-lifestyle:floatingview:2.4.5'
}
```

I checked it [here](https://jitpack.io/p/recruit-lifestyle/floatingview) and found that this one is working.

Also add this to your build.gradle (project)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Also make sure to uncheck the **Gradle Offline** option in Settings.

```
File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle > Uncheck Offline Work
```

Comment: Could you disable the **Gradle Offline** in Settings and see
File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle > Uncheck Offline Work

Comment: I tried to add form file>project structure> dependency >add library dependency  and i searched about it then found it ,pressed applay. is there another way?!

Comment: I am so sorry I meant you had made the Gradle Offline but nothing happened , the error was still happening